# JSON or relational tables for complex user profiles

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am trying to design a Postgres database for holding a variety of information about users and see two obvious ways to go about it - specifically, the different many-many relations.

1. Store the basic user data in a *user_info* table. In separate tables, store the many-many relations like what schools someone attended, places they worked at, and so on. There will be a large number of such tables, (it is easy to add things like what places someone visited, what books they've read, etc. etc. I expect this to grow to a rather large list of tables).
2. In the main *user_info* table, store a JSON blob (properly organized of course) with all this additional info.

Which of these two options should I choose? Naturally, read performance is more important. I know that JSON is generally slower than ordinary relational tables but I am unsure if looking up info from a lot of different tables (as in option 1) will be slower than getting a single json blob and displaying it in the browser. As a further note, the JSONB format, in Postgres, actually has good indexing options.

Update:
Following some comments that a graphdb is what needs to be used: I should clarify the question is **not** about the choice of technology (rdbms vs graph db). But about the choice of data type given the technology (rdbms).

Comment: neither you need a [graph database](http://neo4j.com/books/graph-databases/), which kind of proves this question is **off topic** *because it is **opinion based**, **asking for recommendations** and **too broad** all at the same time*

Comment: Sorry @JarrodRoberson I think you misunderstood. I wasn't asking about what database I need to use. The question is explicitly about what data format. And you removed the postgresql tag - which was there to specify the scope of the question.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson While I understand your rationale behind suggesting a graph db, but I much prefer a traditional solution - mainly for reasons of stability, community, and ease of hiring. FWIW, I had extensively considered a graph db before deciding to switch to Postgres for practical reasons, in spite of the fact that the graph db made life easier in a number of  ways. Sorry, I did not think all this detail was relevant to the question.

Comment: you miss my point, it was not a suggestion to be argued or convinced of it was an example of how off topic the question is

Comment: No, I get the  point. What I don't get is why does _graph database_ in the original comment link to a Neo4j page? They're not the only graphdb around. It would seem the comment is more opinion based than either the question or answer. FWIW, the question has been satisfactorily answered. So I thank you for your kind inputs. Cheers!

Comment: you do not read for comprehension, the point is your question decision to select an answer is 100% your **opinion**, mine is mine, everyone will have different opinions on something like this, questions like this are off topic because there is **no empirically correct answer, only opinions**. That book is about graph databases **in general** if you read for comprehension you might learn a little bit more than [what you already think you know you know which is unfortunate because it is keeping you from knowing what you don't know.](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Dunning-Kruger_effect)

Comment: I read for more than just comprehension. What's amusing is that book which is _about graph databases in general_ has a giant Neo4j logo on the front cover. Would you honestly expect a book written on graph db authored by the founders of a graph db corporation to give a balanced (pro's and cons) perspective of the upcoming technology? Even more interesting is the fact that after getting that book, I get a message from Neo4j staff saying: **After getting the Graph Databases book, people usually ask for these kind of resources: Neo4j Training - free course, completely online**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSQL is great for when you don't know what data you're going to store or how it's going to be used, or it fits well with the list/hash model. Relational databases are great for when you have a lot of certainty about the data, how it will be used, and when it fits into the relational model. I would suggest a hybrid approach, especially given [PostgreSQL 9.2's JSON performance improvements](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql).

- Make traditional relationships for things you know are solid.
- Make use of JSON for data that you want to capture but aren't sure you need.
- For simple lists, make use of PostgreSQL arrays or JSON rather than join tables.
- Abstract this all behind model classes.
- As you gain more knowledge about the data, change how its stored.

For example, make tables for `People`, `Schools`, `Work` and `Places` and join tables between them. Fields like `People.name` and `Places.address` are normal columns. Things like "list of a person's pets" store it as an array of `TEXT` or a `JSON` field until you feel you need a `Pets` table. Any extra information you don't immediately know what you're going to do with like "how big is a school's endowment" put into a JSON metadata column.

Using model classes allows you to refactor your database without worrying about every piece of code that touches the database. Just be sure that all code which makes assumptions about the table structure goes into model methods.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question - until I know enough to formalize it as a separate table, use JSON in the interim.